# Localforage returns undefined when app updated in iOs Ionic3, if app switched back to old version the local storage works fine

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic3, localforage

On Ionic3 App i am using localforage indexedDB for storing authtoken. When i upgrade the app localstorage comes out to be undefined. Whereas if i reinstall old app, Authtoken is displayed fine.

I am not sure what the problem is, is the localstorage again initialized with empty values but has old values still stored